# How to make journalctl show the apache2 error.log?

Tags: logs, apache-httpd, journalctl

Specific: I know I can use cat /var/log/apache2/error.log, but journalctl is now the "official" log viewer, so it has to show all logs. I hate using 2 tools for a task that one tool should be enough. journalctl -u apache2 does not show the error logs.

Answer (score 2):

If you want `apache2` to log using the `systemd` journal, you will need to change your configuration to use `mod_journald` for logging.  You can find the documentation for `mod_journald` [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_journald.html).

Do note that the documentation recommends against using `mod_journald` if you have a high volume of logging, due to the potential performance impact.